# String interpolation in Redactor

Tags: templating, redactor, string

I have a redactor field whose HTML contents contain links to other parts of the website.

How do I render variables located in the HTML content of a Redactor field in Twig?

Sample redactor content:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

In output of this results in the braces being encoded:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="%7B%7B%20siteUrl%20%7D%7D/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="%7B%7B%20siteUrl%20%7D%7D/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I want it the output to be whatever `siteUrl` is. Eg on **localhost**:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redactor fields are not meant to process twig both for security reasons (as they can be changed by any user) and for usability (you cannot expect authors to remember / preserve twig tags).

In your specific example, the site url is probably not necessary (starting a URL with / will link to the current domain just fine) - so you would not actually need twig.

However I cannot think of one good reason to build a menu in a redactor field. I would either include it directly in the page templates (.twig files) or use a matrix field as a [content builder](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-content-builder-in-craft-cms).

Comment: Yeah, it isn't clean, but it's actually part of data we are migrating over from client's older project.